# How to get the value of result of onPostExcecute to onCreate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How can I get the value of the result of my `AsyncTask` right here.

```
    public class JSONPicture extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJSON =buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("tbl_user");

            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);


            String firstname = finalObject.getString("userImage");

            return firstname;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(result, ivUser);
            Log.d(TAG, result);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling it on the `onStart` like this. So i can load. When it load I want to get the string of the image.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    new JSONPicture().execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/profile/profileImage.php?username="+pref.getString("username","").toString());

}
```

I want to get the url of the image when I'm clicking the image like this.

```
        ivUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, ivUser.toString);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  The purpose of an AsyncTask is to run in parallel.  If you were to wait for the result, there's no reason to use an AsyncTask.  By forcing the UI thread to wait, you'll leave the app unresponsive to the user.  If you do it for too long, it will cause the app to crash due to the watchdog timer.

The correct way to do things is instead to put all the logic that requires the result in onPostExecute.  If you need to, put up a loading bar or other UI elements to show that the app is waiting until you have the result.

Comment: Neither. Main is used in desktop java, not in android. Basically main is written for you in the android framework, your entry point is the launcher activity's onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more mechanical way and store the value in cache storage where you can retrieve from any place in your app. I would recommend tinyDB.

gradle `compile 'com.mukesh:tinydb:1.0.1'

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());

tinyDB.putString("key",value);
```

then you can retrieve the value from any place within the app using this line of code.

```
tinyDB.getString("key");
```

Mechanical but efficient. Just call the async task method in the onCreate first then call tinyDB.getString. Store the string in tinyDB from onPostExecute.